# bluemix-appid No such module"BluemixAppID'

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I am setting up APP ID on IOS Swift Project.

- Set up the Pods, and seeing BluemixAppID in the Pods.
- Set up the URLS etc
- Added the error and the framework search path below

POD File

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PS_1' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
    pod 'BluemixAppID'

  target 'PS_1Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'PS_1UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Project Dir

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 kosalan  staff  136 22 Jul 23:54 DerivedData
drwxr-xr-x  11 kosalan  staff  374 23 Jul 00:08 PS_1
drwxr-xr-x   5 kosalan  staff  170 23 Jul 00:03 PS_1.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   3 kosalan  staff  102 22 Jul 22:39 PS_1.xcworkspace
drwxr-xr-x   4 kosalan  staff  136 28 May 13:13 PS_1Tests
drwxr-xr-x   4 kosalan  staff  136 28 May 13:13 PS_1UITests
-rw-r--r--@  1 kosalan  staff  415 22 Jul 23:32 Podfile
-rw-r--r--   1 kosalan  staff  422 22 Jul 23:33 Podfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x  11 kosalan  staff  374 22 Jul 23:32 Pods
-rw-r--r--   1 kosalan  staff    7 28 May 13:19 README.md
Kosalans-MBP:PS_1 kosalan$ pwd
/Users/kosalan/Documents/Projects/PS_1/PS_1
Kosalans-MBP:PS_1 kosalan$

Kosalans-MBP:Pods kosalan$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  5 kosalan  staff  170 22 Jul 22:43 BMSAnalyticsAPI
drwxr-xr-x  5 kosalan  staff  170 22 Jul 22:43 BMSCore
drwxr-xr-x  5 kosalan  staff  170 22 Jul 23:30 BluemixAppID
drwxr-xr-x  2 kosalan  staff   68 22 Jul 23:32 Headers
drwxr-xr-x  2 kosalan  staff   68 22 Jul 22:38 Local Podspecs
-rw-r--r--  1 kosalan  staff  422 22 Jul 23:33 Manifest.lock
drwxr-xr-x  4 kosalan  staff  136 22 Jul 22:38 Pods.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x  8 kosalan  staff  272 22 Jul 23:33 Target Support Files
Kosalans-MBP:Pods kosalan$
```

[xcode screenshot - framework search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1185.png)

[xcode screenshot - error along with full build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O763O.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by opening .xcworkspace in the proj dir vs the .xcodeproj.